# Java thread is hung when closing ActiveMQ connection

Tags: groovy, jms, activemq-classic

When trying to close an ActiveMQ Connection after publishing a message to a queue, the java thread hangs as it appears the connection never closes.  Is there additional logic or an additional property we can put on the broker url to have a timeout on the attempted connection close?

We're using the failover transport with a tcp connection.  Here's a code snippet where we're trying to close the connection.  In the finally block, when trying to do the connection.close, it's never closing and continuing on, and therefore blocking all future messages on this queue from being consumed.

FYI..This is a Grails 3.2.4 project

```
try {
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue(queueName))

    TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message)
    textMessage.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, resendTime)

    if (correlationId) {
        textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId)
    }

    producer.send(textMessage)
} finally {
    log.debug("Attempting to close the session after sending message to queue ${queueName}.  Message = ${message}")
    session.close()

    log.debug("Attempting to close the connection after sending message to queue ${queueName}. Message = ${message}")
    if (connection) {
        connection.close()
    } else {
        log.warn("No connection exists while attempting to close after sending message to queue ${queueName}.  Message = ${message}")
    }
}
```

And here's a snippet of our connection:

```
brokerURL: 'failover:(tcp://serverAddress:port,vm://localhost)?initialReconnectDelay=5000&maxReconnectDelay=10000&timeout=5000&randomize=false&priorityBackup=true'
```

Comment: Can you get a thread dump to see what the thread may be waiting on?

Comment: and what is your resendTime set to ? Does it hang also if you take out the code with AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY ?